# What does this enum mean?

Tags: c

I saw this line of code today and had no idea what it does.

```
typedef enum {
  SomeOptionKeys = 1 << 0 // ?
} SomeOption;
```

Some usage or example would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `1 << 0 == 1`, I don't see the point. Is this the complete `enum`? These constructs are often used with `|`.

Comment: @WTP probably it's part of it. It's common to see multiple values in the enum as `fst = 1 << 0, sec = 1 << 1, thr = 1 << 2` just for the sake of completeness (in columns, of course, not in this one-line).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it defines an enumerated type that is supposed to contain a set of flags. You'd expect to see more of them defined, like this:

```
typedef enum {
  FirstOption = 1 << 0,
  SecondOption = 1 << 1,
  ThirdOption = 1 << 2
} SomeOption;
```

Since they are defined as powers of two, each value corresponds to a single bit in an integer variable. Thus, you can use the bitwise operators to combine them and to test if they are set. This is a common pattern in C code.

You could write code like this that combines them:

```
SomeOption myOptions = FirstOption | ThirdOption;
```

And you could check which options are set like this:

```
if (myOptions & ThirdOption)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: +1 as it's in my opinion the most complete answer here and I learnt something from it too.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 4):

The value of `SomeOptionKeys` is one, this is a useful representation when working with flags:

```
typedef enum {
  flag1 = 1 << 0, // binary 00000000000000000000000000000001
  flag2 = 1 << 1, // binary 00000000000000000000000000000010
  flag3 = 1 << 2, // binary 00000000000000000000000000000100
  flag4 = 1 << 3, // binary 00000000000000000000000000001000
  flag5 = 1 << 4, // binary 00000000000000000000000000010000
  // ...
} SomeOption;
```

Whit way each flag has only one bit set, and they could be represented in a bitmap.

Edit:

Although, I have to say, that I might be missing something, but it seems redundent to me to use enums for that. Since you lose any advantage of enums in this configuration, you may as well use `#define`:

```
#define flag1 (1<<0)
#define flag2 (1<<1)
#define flag3 (1<<2)
#define flag4 (1<<3)
#define flag5 (1<<4)
```

Answer (score 2):

It just sets the enum to the value 1.  It is probably intended to indicate that the values are to be powers of 2.  The next one would maybe be assigned `1 << 1`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

<< is the left shift operator.  In general, this is used when you want your enums to mask a single bit.  In this case, the shift doesn't actually do anything since it's 0, but you might see it pop up in more complex cases.

An example might look like:

```
typedef enum {
   OptionKeyA = 1<<0,
   OptionKeyB = 1<<1,
   OptionKeyC = 1<<2,
} OptionKeys;
```

Then if you had some function that took an option key, you could use the enum as a bitmask to check if an option is set.

```
int ASet( OptionKeys x){
   return (x & OptionKeyA);
}
```

Or if you had a flag bitmap and wanted to set one option:

```
myflags | OptionKeyB
```